# error when using requestJWTUserToken, just replace my account info SDK project, junit code

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am running the official SDK Junit codes, and it works fine. But when I change  the account info into mine, exception occur.
Debug says it return http status of 400 when posting to endpoint "/oauth/token",

I have save my private key generated in docusign admin page, into "docusign_private_key.txt"

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient (BaseUrl);
//String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

try
{

    // IMPORTANT NOTE:
    // the first time you ask for a JWT access token, you should grant access by making the following call
    // get DocuSign OAuth authorization url:
    //String oauthLoginUrl = apiClient.getJWTUri(IntegratorKey, RedirectURI, OAuthBaseUrl);
    // open DocuSign OAuth authorization url in the browser, login and grant access
    //Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(oauthLoginUrl));
    // END OF NOTE
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = null;
    try
    {
        privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes (Paths.get (privateKeyFullPath) );
    }
    catch (IOException ioExcp)
    {
        Assert.assertEquals (null, ioExcp);
    }
    if (privateKeyBytes == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    java.util.List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add (OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
    scopes.add (OAuth.Scope_IMPERSONATION);
    OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken (IntegratorKey, UserId, scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error log?

Comment: As @Haem mentions if you have the actual error message or description that would help, though I've posted an answer that might be your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

The SDK JUnit code defines a parameter called "UserId", it should be filled by "API Username" , not "API Account ID" from Admin page.

Thanks for all you kind people.

Answer (score 0):

Per the note in the comments, you need to grant one-time user consent per key for your app to use it, have you done that?  If you have Organizations enabled (which is an enterprise feature) then you can do it across the entire account, otherwise you'll need to grant consent manually on a one-by-one (ie user by user) basis.

If granting consent manually (which is what most integrations do) you need to configure your `Integrator Key` with the Redirect URI you will be passing through code, then redirect your user to the following URL in a web browser (the "-d" part of the URL means this would be for the demo environment):

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
    response_type=YOUR_RESPONSE_TYPE
    &scope=open_id
    &client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATOR_KEY
    &state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
    &admin_consent_scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES
```

If done correctly the user will be taken to the standard DocuSign login page.  After successful login they can explicitly grant consent to your app and will then be re-directed back to your app through the Redirect URI param you configured.

Here is a guide that explains how to obtain consent using either method:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent